# Let f:G to H be 1-1 homomorphism show that order of f(a) divides the order of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f:G \to H$ be an injective homomorphism. Show that order of $f(a) \in H$ divides the order of G.

Let the order of $|G|=n$. I'm not sure where to go from here. I've seen examples showing it divides an element $g$ but not $G$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $G$ is a finite group.

Let $|a|=k$, then $[f(a)]^k=f(a^k)=f(e_{G})=e_{H}$. This tells us that the order of $f(a)$ divides $k$. But in a finite group, the order of every element divides the order of the group. So $k | |G|$. By transitivity $|f(a)| \big| |G|$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|G|=n$ and $f:G \to H$ be an injective homomorphism. Now, we know $|g|=m|n$ by Lagrange's theorem and since $f$ is a homomorphism we have $e_H=f(e_G)=f(g^m)=(f(g))^m$. Hence, the order of $f(g)$, call it $k$ divides $m$. Since $k|m$ and $m|n$ we have $k|n$. This gives the result. We don't need the injectivity of $f$.

Comment: With injectivity it's actually a silly problem. Why not prove the order of $f(a)$ is the order of $a$?

Comment: That may have actually been the intent of the question and OP misunderstood.